# Should I migrate this question?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/i-want-to-be-like-madeon-where-do-i-start) on music.se and later realized that a [similar question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/i-want-to-learn-how-to-make-electronic-music-where-do-i-start) had already been asked here. The question here is a bit long-winded and has a broader focus, but the accepted answer is great. I am interested in seeing more answers to the question or, as I would (obviously) prefer, answers to my specific questions.

I am not familiar enough with the two sites or with the field in general to judge whether I should:

- leave my question there
- have it migrated here
- close it there and place a bounty on the question here

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

I think your question has merit on both sites: electronic music is often as much (or more) about production as it is about musicianship. I don't know what the Music.SE community thinks, but I think it's quite on-topic here, just like the question you linked.

It sounds like that similar question has answered most of what you were looking for, but you still have some specific questions that weren't covered. I think your questions will get better answers if you **ask them as new, well-focused questions here** rather than just migrating the broader question from Music.SE, or putting a somewhat-vague bounty on a question that already has a great answer.

This is my opinion; more input is of course welcome!